# VTK Python Wrapper - Exporting Surface Plot

Tags: c++, python-3.5, vtk, paraview

I'm using VTK 8.0.1 and python 3.5 and am brand new to VTK. I am trying to export a surface plot using vtkPlotSurface.

By referencing [TestSurfacePlot.cxx](https://www.vtk.org/gitweb?p=VTK.git;a=blob;f=Filters/General/Testing/Python/TestPointConnectivityFilter.py) I have successfully created a surface plot and have been able to render it in python (even though it doesn't really look like a surface plot).

```py
import vtk
import math as m
import numpy as np

## Set things up
chart = vtk.vtkChartXYZ()
view = vtk.vtkContextView()
view.GetRenderWindow().SetSize(800,800)
view.GetScene().AddItem(chart)

## Create a surface
table = vtk.vtkTable()
numPoints = 70;
inc = 9.424778 / (numPoints - 1);
for i in range(0,numPoints):
    arr = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
    table.AddColumn(arr)

table.SetNumberOfRows(numPoints)
for i in range(0,numPoints):
    x = i * inc;
    for j in range(0,numPoints):
        y  = j * inc;
        table.SetValue(i, j, m.sin(m.sqrt(x*x + y*y)))

# Using table, create a surface plot
test = vtk.vtkPlotSurface()
test.SetXRange(0,9.424778)
test.SetYRange(0,9.424778)
test.SetInputData(table)

# Start visualizing the surface plot
chart.AddPlot(test)
view.GetRenderWindow().SetMultiSamples(0)
view.GetInteractor().Initialize()
view.GetRenderWindow().Render()

out = vtk.vtkOBJExporter()
out.SetFilePrefix("test")
out.SetInput(chart)
out.Write()


view.GetInteractor().Start()
```

In order to better visualize what I've made, I wanted to try and export it and then visualize using Paraview/Visit. However, I'm struggling to find any concrete examples where this type of vtk object is exported...

I have tried adding the following:

```
out = vtk.vtkOBJExporter()
out.SetFilePrefix("test")
out.SetInput(chart)
out.Write()
```

But end up with the following type error:

```
TypeError: SetInput argument 1: method requires a vtkRenderWindow, a vtkContextView was provided.
```

Can anyone provide assistance? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data you are importing? Points? Are they on a regular grid in X and Y and only the Z dimension varies? There are different ways to compute a surface from the data and I have one in mind, but need more info on what the underlying data is. I think you'll be happier generating a polygonal geometry that you can export to OBJ if possible rather than going through the VTK charts capabilities, which are kind of a dead end as far as transforming data is concerned.

Comment: @CoryQuammen the data I am working with are time dependent X,Y points on a regular grid - think of a mathematical function that outputs X,Y data in time - e.g. f(x,y,t) = t sin(x) sin(y)

So my thought process was to represent this time dependent X,Y data through a surface plot - or rather a series of surface plots. But I am definitely open to other suggestions on how to better visualize the data.

Comment: This kind of data is readily transformed into a surface plot. Does the input file contain X and Y coordinate values along with f(x,y,t)?

Comment: As of now, no. But there is no reason that I couldn't do so. I would just need to know the best format for VTK to read in the data.

Comment: If you add x and y coordinate columns to a CSV file, you can import the CSV file as a table and run the **Table to Structured Grid** filter to convert it  to a 2-dimensional structured grid. Set the **X Column** to the imported X column, the **Y Column** similarly, and the **Z Column** to the data column. This will give you a height surface of your function.

Comment: If you interact with the plot (mouse drag) you will see the plot as a surface. The piece of code at the end of the test example (using `vtkContextMouseEvent`) rotates the inial view by simulating mouse events. Does exporting work if you simply replace `out.SetInput(chart)` by `out.SetInput(view.GetRenderWindow())`?

Comment: To make your plot appear, you are missing the statement `chart.SetGeometry(vtk.vtkRectf(10.0, 10.0, 630, 470))`. Giving `view.GetRenderWindow()` to `out.SetInput` changes the error to `vtkOBJExporter (0x7ff195226040): no actors found for writing .obj file.`
See, however, [this question](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/vtkOBJExporter-and-vtkOBJReader-obj-files-do-not-have-colors-td1239186.html), it might be that your export won't get colors (although it's an old post).

Answer (score 1):

You might benefit from using [PyVista](https://docs.pyvista.org) as it makes creating these types of spatially reference datasets and rendering much more user-friendly. I would avoid using a `vtkTable` like you have above and move towards VTK data objects that actually represent meshes/surfaces.

```py
import pyvista as pv
import numpy as np

# Create a spatial reference
numPoints = 70
inc = 9.424778 / (numPoints - 1)
x = np.arange(0, numPoints) * inc
y = np.arange(0, numPoints) * inc
xx, yy, _ = np.meshgrid(x, y, [0])
zz = np.sin(np.sqrt(xx*xx + yy*yy))
# Make a PyVista/VTK mesh
surface = pv.StructuredGrid(xx, yy, zz)

# Plot it!
surface.plot(show_edges=True, show_grid=True, notebook=False)

# or save it out for opening in ParaView
surface.save("my_surface.vtk")
```

[image]